# Making self hosted Facebook App working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recived an facebook app that existed under:

`https://www.facebook.com/pages/Zapaleni-Smakiem/314603481920237?id=314603481920237&sk=app_456052154430227`

Company who maintained it cased to exist. We recived source code. And no access to old profile. So we need to make app work on new sever and on new facebook profile.

Facebook apps are so unintuitive and i have no idea how to add it. I got company profile, how to add app to it? I add app but it does not show anywhere. There is no link to it. Nothing.

I changed APPID and SecretKey to new ones. When i enter a url where app is hosted all i get is an error where i see that domain is unauthorized even tho it is in app settings.

new APP url is here: http://e-palenie.info/smakdlaciebie

Do I need some kind of special page? Got a company page. What do I lack? I'm close to hanging myself.

Comment: did you change the domain on the appconsole of your app ?

Comment: If i knew what is that, where is that etc. is it on app code or in developers.facebook.com?

Comment: well its under `developers.facebook.com`,go into the settings of your app and change the domain, which would probably be pointing to old domain

Comment: Old facebook account is lost. Not used anymore. App is suppoused to work on new account.
If you mean Apps > {Appname} > Settings > App Domains > value is e-palenie.info just like server where app is being hosted. Server has got https enabled. Added platform > Website > and added url of app. Maybe i should add platfrom and select APP on Facebook?

Comment: yes, FB account was the only way of connecting to your app, if the account is lost or locked, even the app will be locked. just do one thing create the app over the new account with the settings mapping to production environment and try , it should work smoothly.

Comment: I got source code of an app. Old administrator company refuses to give administrator account access since many other client profiles are on it.
We already set app on our own server. got new account. Only thing we need is to make it work with new appid and on new page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45185/discussion-between-gacek-and-dreamweiver)

Comment: I'm somehow closer. Still can't figure out how to make that small app window. Only got full size window like for games.

Answer (score 0):

I hired somone to fix app for me. Apparently app requires a namespace (even tho facebook page states differently) and proper linking.

```
var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
oauth_url += '?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx';
oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/namespace_name');// namespace_name requires a namespace of an app to be writen it seems. and thats what I lacked.
oauth_url += '&scope=publish_actions,user_likes';

window.top.location = oauth_url;
```

Won't mark this answer as best one, since maybe someone will eventually be able on this answer provide a better one.